# How can I center a button on view programmatically

Tags: swift, uikit

I am trying to center a Button onto the bottom of a view but it never appears. The only time it appears is when I uncomment `takePhotoButton.frame`. What is the proper way to do this?

```
 import UIKit
 import AVFoundation


class InputViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       let photoPreviewImageView = UIImageView()
        photoPreviewImageView.frame = view.bounds
        photoPreviewImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        view.addSubview(photoPreviewImageView)

        let imageOfPhotoButton = UIImage(named: "smallcircle.circle.fill") as UIImage?
        let takePhotoButton = UIButton(type: .custom) as UIButton
        takePhotoButton.setImage(imageOfPhotoButton, for: .normal)
        //takePhotoButton.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 60, height: 60) // It will appear with this code however i took it away because im trying to center it at the bottom of the screen
        takePhotoButton.center = view.center
        photoPreviewImageView.addSubview(takePhotoButton)

    }




}
```

Comment: No need to cast to UIImage, the initialiser will alway return and optional UIImage. Same for UIButton while the initialiser returns a non-optional.

Answer (score 1):

Use constraint anchors. After you add the takePhotoButton set them the following way:

```
takePhotoButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoPreviewImageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
takePhotoButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: photoPreviewImageView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
```

This will set make your button have the same bottom and center as it's container.

Comment: Don't forgot about button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Comment: It crashed and I got this error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600003a89700 "UIButton:0x7f9e90c2fcf0.bottom"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600003a883c0 "UIImageView:0x7f9e90c16a00.bottom"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'`

Comment: Did you add those lines after you added the button as a subview?

Comment: Yes that fixed the crash however the button still does not show.

Comment: That's because it has zero bounds. Set the frame with x and y at zero and it should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Good day,
you have to add constraint.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var loginButton : UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = .red
        button.tintColor = .white
        return button
    }()




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        constraintsInit()
    }


    func constraintsInit(){
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            loginButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
            loginButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
            loginButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            loginButton.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor,constant: 30),
            loginButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor,constant: -30),
        ])
    }

}
```

on youtube you can find several people that explain how create the views, using only code.